# SML datatypes in 32 bit linux and 64 bit linux

Tags: sml

I presume that in Standard ML :

- int is 32 bit on 32bit linux

On 64 bit linux is int also 32 bit? Furthermore is there a place (url) where the size of different datatypes is outlined, for Standard ML? Thanks

Comment: int always remains 32 bit even in a 64 bit OS. The difference between 32 bit and 64 bit OSes are their memory addressing capacities. For the data type sizes, just google them.

Comment: Cool thanks. I did spend some time googling (and also searched in Harpers book) before I asked this rather basic question, but could not find the answer (and the answer was not obvious to me because in Haskell Int seems to be 32 bit on 32 bit systems and 64 bit on 64 bit systems).

Comment: @MarkGarcia No, it's not always 32 bit. It's implementation specific and can very well depend on whether the platform is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Int.precision`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG%3aINTEGER.precision%3aVAL) to determine the size of the built in `Int` type.

The sizes of the `Int` type isn't language defined, but implementation defined, so the answer you're looking for depends on your choice of compiler/interpreter.

Moscow ML provides 31-bit integers on 32 bit machines and 63-bit integers on 64-bit machines, for instance.<sup>([source](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosmllib/Int.html#precision-val))</sup>

Note that many implementations provide several int types, some of which may be arbitrary precision. For each of these, a corresponding `precision` function will exist to tell you the precision provided by that given type.

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can convert Int.precision to a string? I have just installed mlton and am trying to "print" it so that I can see the value of Int.precision. Thanks

Comment: @artella Int.precision is an `int option`. So you'll need to extract it from the option type (using `valOf`, for instance), and then convert the `int` to `string` using `Int.toString`.

Comment: Perfect! Using valOf I managed to verify that int is 32 bit on 32 bit ubuntu (when compiled in mlton). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The size of integers is implementation-specific - it's not specified by the standard. In MoscowML uses 31-bit integers on 32-bit platforms and 63-bit integers on 64-bit platforms according to [its documentation](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosmllib/Int.html).

SML/NJ apparently uses 31-bit integers on both 64-bit and 32-bit systems (I say apparently because I didn't find this documented anywhere - I just tested it on my 64-bit machine).

In MLton the size of Int can even be set using the `-default-type` command line argument to the compiler.

Comment: Aha! And how about mlton? And how did you test it? Thanks.

Comment: @artella As Sebastian just pointed out, you can use Int.precision to find out the precision. But I simply tried to type in various numbers into the REPL to see which ones caused an "integer too big" error ;-)

Comment: Cool thanks, just saw Sebastian's answer and am trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the high-end SML implementation [Poly/ML](http://www.polyml.org) provides unbounded (big) ints by default, so you get a faithful model of mathematical integers without any worries (both correctness and efficiency for the usual symbolic applications).

Answer (score -1):

The 32 or 64 bit is referred to the dimension of address. So the datatype are the same size but the pointer size change because a 64 bit system use 64 bit to address the memory

Comment: It is perfectly valid for an implementation of SML to use different sizes of integers on 32-bit vs. 64-bit platforms.